# How can I combine Jest matchers, especially for mocked arguments?

Tags: jestjs

I have some tests that accurately test my code's expected behavior, but that are rather brittle because I'm using literals. I'd like to make broader assertions about the shape of something. For example:

```
expect(mockedModule.mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(mockedModule.mockFunction).toHaveLastBeenCalledWith(
  "argument1",
  {
     field1: expect.stringMatching(/^argument1/), // but I also care about several other string matches
                                                  // and I _do not_ care about the order.
  },
);
```

I could obviously repeatedly call `toHaveLastBeenCalledWith` with `expect.any()` littered through my code. But that's not very succinct, and it's not a great way to express the invariants I'm expecting.

Ideally I'd have something like:

```
expect(mockedModule.mockFunction).toHaveLastBeenCalledWith(
  "argument1",
  {
     field1: expect.all(
          expect.stringMatching(/^argument1/),
          expect.any(
             expect.stringMatching("42"),
             expect.stringMatching("8675309"),
          )
     )
  },
)
```

or the equivalent:

```
expect(mockedModule.mockFunction).toHaveLastBeenCalledWith(
  "argument1",
  {
     field1: expect.all(
          expect.stringMatching(/^argument1/).and(
              expect.stringMatching("42").or(
                expect.stringMatching("8675309)
              )
          ),
     )
  },
)
```

But I have not found any functionality similar to this. This is most important for `toHaveBeenCalledWith` calls, where I never get a copy of the actual value, but have to create a matcher.

Comment: Why not just pull out the value so you can make multiple assertions on it *outside* `toHaveLastBeenCalledWith`?

Comment: Is there any easy way to do that? I'm all ears.

Comment: To get access to the parameters that were passed? Sure, it's all on the mock object: https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mock-property